# Joomla: addStyleDeclaration inserts commented styles

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

My Joomla article uses Jumi to include a php file.

The php file uses `$document->addStyleDeclaration` It all seems to work, except that the added style is commented out by the method! The new style is surrounded by HTML comments.

Joomla 1.5.21. Suggestions appreciated!

```
php file:
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( "Direct Access Is Not Allowed" );

$style = <<<FOOBAR
    @import url("http://foo.css");
    .gfg-entry {height: 6.9em;}
    #feed-control {width : 500px; padding : 10px;}
FOOBAR;

$document =& JFactory::getDocument(); 
$document->addStyleDeclaration ($style);
?>
```

Below, what is getting added to the page's Head section.
Note the added <!-- and --> comments bracketing:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
<!--
@import url("http://foo.css");
.gfg-entry {height: 6.9em;} 
#feed-control {width : 500px; padding : 10px;}
-->
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Oops, it's a feature, not a bug. Joomla inserts the <!-- and --> to make the resulting page pristine XHTML.

The browser ignores HTML-style comments within style tags. Style tags use /* for comments */